# Can't highlight text

Tags: html, css, google-maps, dom, z-index

Check http://discoveryobstacleruns.nl/. I can't highlight any text on the site, but it doesn't seem to be a z-index issue and it doesn't have any other means to block text highlighting. Any idea what's causing it?

Edit: disabling JS seems to do the trick, which leads to believe it's Google Maps causing it. However, all elements above the map are clickable, the content is clearly on top of the map so why wouldn't I be able to highlight text?

So, apparently

```
document.getElementById('map').bind('click', function(e) {
    if(e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
 });
```

fixes it but gives an error message in console. Which makes sense because it should be:

```
document.getElementById('map').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
 });
```

but that doesn't work at all (doesn't give an error though). What gives??

Comment: Maybe because it's on top of the Google map?

Comment: Deleting the map from the dom doesn't change it though. Edit: disabling JS does the trick, so I guess it IS the map. Why would it do that? The content is above the map so why would the map affect text highlighting?

Comment: Maybe something with the ::moz-selection in your css, try to play around with that a bit.

Comment: Try increasing the z-index on some elements? Or play around with the body css a bit, since that's the only place where your content and your map are both in.

Comment: I tried, but no luck... Really strange. Not calling google maps fixes it so the only thing I can think of is that Google Maps itself sets some preventDefault(); type of function of mouseclick.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have anything above it? Like something transparent? I see some opacity stuff in your css.

Comment: If I had, I would also not be able to click things. It's really weird... I'm pretty sure it's Google Maps doing it but I don't know how or why.